# awaiting for api data then render react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am trying to make a slider component getting data from api but I can not figure it out how to get data first and then feed it to the component. As far as I can tell in my implementation, the component tries to render before data is pulled from the api.

```
  const [slides, setSlides] = useState([]);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataFetch = async () => {
      const data = await (
        await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/data")
      ).json();

      setSlides(data);
    };

    dataFetch();
  }, []);

  const prevSlide = () => {
    const isFirstSlide = currentIndex === 0;
    const newIndex = isFirstSlide ? slides.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
  };

  const nextSlide = () => {
    const isLastSlide = currentIndex === slides.length - 1;
    const newIndex = isLastSlide ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
  };

  const goToSlide = (slideIndex) => {
    setCurrentIndex(slideIndex);
  };

 return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slides[currentIndex].url})` }}>
        <h1>{slides[currentIndex].name}</h1>
        <p>{slides[currentIndex].description}</p>
      </div>

      {/* Left Arrow */}
      <div>
        <BsChevronCompactLeft onClick={prevSlide} size={30} />
      </div>
      {/* Right Arrow */}
      <div>
        <BsChevronCompactRight onClick={nextSlide} size={30} />
      </div>
      <div>
        {slides.map((slide, slideIndex) => (
          <div key={slideIndex} onClick={() => goToSlide(slideIndex)}>
            <RxDotFilled />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Looks alright so far. The component is supposed to render without data, and later, after `setSlides(data)`, to be rerendered. That's how React works - you render it empty and rerender after stuff has changed, e.g. by `useEffect`. The alternative would be SSR where the data is loaded on the server-side and then the initial page gets send to the client. But that would be more difficult to implement..

Comment: I have updated with the render content. When it tries to render I get Cannot read the properties of undefined (reading 'url'). If I try to log the slides after useEffect it shows an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

When rendering for the first time - before `useEffect` got invoked even -, `slides` is an empty array. Accessing an item from an empty array will return `undefined`, and the property `url` cannot be read from that.

You could add a clause like `if (slides.length === 0) return null` or `if (!slides[currentIndex]) return null` right above your existing `return` statement no render nothing, or you could return some loading animation instead.

In general, keep in mind how React is working: First it renders the component with the initial `states`. Then, `useEffect` will be invoked. If it modifies the component's state (or any state, that is), it will be rerendered - this time possibly with loaded values.